# How to create multiple repeating data frame or matrices in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, apply

I am trying to make multiple data frames (df_1,,, df_N) with the same structure.
For now, I have made them all individually, but I imagine there should be more efficient way of writing the codes.

Below are the matrices I created (only three for now, but can be more than 100 later on)

```
quantileMatrix_1 <- matrix(NA,nrow=ncol(outDf_1), ncol = 3)
for(jj in 1:ncol(outDf_1)){
  quantiles <- outDf_1[,jj] %>% quantile(probs=c(.5,.025,.975))
  quantileMatrix_1[jj,] <- quantiles
}

quantileMatrix_2 <- matrix(NA,nrow=ncol(outDf_2), ncol = 3)
for(jj in 1:ncol(outDf_2)){
  quantiles <- outDf_2[,jj] %>% quantile(probs=c(.5,.025,.975))
  quantileMatrix_2[jj,] <- quantiles
}

quantileMatrix_3 <- matrix(NA,nrow=ncol(outDf_3), ncol = 3)
for(jj in 1:ncol(outDf_3)){
  quantiles <- outDf_3[,jj] %>% quantile(probs=c(.5,.025,.975))
  quantileMatrix_3[jj,] <- quantiles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use another for loop, to put every df in a list.

```
my_matrix <- list()

for (d in 1:100) {
  quantileMatrix_d <- matrix(NA,nrow=ncol(outDf_1), ncol = 3)
  for(jj in 1:ncol(outDf_1)){
    quantiles <- outDf_1[,jj] %>% quantile(probs=c(.5,.025,.975))
    quantileMatrix_d[jj,] <- quantiles
  }
  my_matrix[[d]] <- quantileMatrix_d
}
```